# Wordpress как убрать фильтрацию тегов в шаблоне dazzling?

Tags: php, wordpress, filter

Добрый день/вечер я установил wordpress на хостинг, также установил тему Dazzling и вот в чем проблема:

Когда выводиться лента постов/новостей, лента фильтрует во всех постах html теги, но, если перейти на саму страницу поста/новости все ок, все теги на своих местах. Не могу понять как и где включена эта фильтрация то ли в самом wordpress'e либо в шаблоне. Как это отключить?

Этот эффект на сайте можно посмотреть тут: http://startoswift.netai.net/

Comment: `Надеюсь вам тут понравиться!`?

Comment: да это так для теста я только позавчера его установил. не обращайте внимание

Comment: Да я про мягкий знак.

Comment: ааа это  у меня с русским не особо, но мак помогает исправлять ошибки : )